# What is difference between statistical semantics and distributional semantics?

Tags: semantics, information-retrieval, information-extraction, statistical-semantics

I am searching for appropriate techniques to carry out some experiments of information retrieval. I have basic idea of statistical semantics which is mainly consider as an internal semantics and used as a measure of similarity between units of text (terms) and is evaluated based on the statistical analysis of term occurrence patterns. So i need to contrast against distributional semantics. Which is better to be used and why ?